# Cannot send touch tones for press number or enter card number?

Tags: samsung, audio, troubleshooting, dialer-codes, touch

I have a Samsung Flip 3, when asked to push a number or enter my card number was not working despite many efforts. I can tell you the solution I found on the forum from years ago after much searching was absolutely the fix:

Settings, Accessibility, Interaction and Dexterity, Touch and hold delay, change from Short to Long. Problem solved.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi, this forum works differently, its a question and answers style.  If you want to do both, then please separate the answer into teh answer section.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. We appreciate everyone's contribution. However, looks like a duplicate question about the same issue already existed. Thus, this question has been closed as a duplicate of the older question. Keep contributing though! :)